# Iterate through an array of nested objects to collect objects that lack a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I need to iterate through the array of objects as long as the `children` key has values in it.

Each object in the array will have an individual `children` array and I need to check if the `timeGroupName` exists in each of the objects.

And finally, if the `timeGroupName` is missing in any of the objects, return something to indicate that `timeGroupName` does not exist. I want to use recursion here.

Sample Object:

```
[
  {
    name: "test",
    timeGroupName: "NupurGroup",
    type: "node",
    id: 1592208617196,
    children: [
      {
        name: "sid",
        timeGroupName: "NupurGroup",
        type: "node",
        id: 1592210050837,
        children: [
          {
            name: "rush",
            timeGroupName: "NupurGroup",
            type: "node",
            id: 1592210076303,
            children: []
          },
          {
            name: "1",
            timeGroupName: "NupurGroup",
            type: "store",
            storeId: "5c46e5fde6d3c2293e1f53b6",
            id: 1592210057381,
            children: []
          }
        ],
        collapsedStore: false,
        collapsedGroup: false
      }
    ],
    collapsedGroup: false
  }
];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this recursive function:

```
const findMissing = data => (data || []).flatMap(item => 
    ("timeGroupName" in item ? [] : [item.id]).concat(findMissing(item.children)) 
);
```

This will return an array with the id values of all the objects that have no "timeGroupName" property. In your example all objects have it, so the above function would return `[]` for it.